# How to redirect requests from apache2 to tomcat7 on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu12.04 when installed using apt-get command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I installed Apache2 and Tomcat7 on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu12.04 using command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Now for tomcat
`CATALINA_HOME` is `/usr/share/tomcat7`  (`bin` and `lib` folders of tomcat)
`CATALINA_BASE` is `/var/lib/tomcat7` (`webapps` folder is in there)

For Apache
Apache modules : `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`
virtual hosts : `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`
configuration file :    `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
Apache configuration file `httpd.conf` is empty.

How can I redirect all request from Apache2 to Tomcat7?
Means for Example if I enter `10.121.143.116:80` in browser, it will hit `10.121.143.116:8080`

Kindly suggest as I am finding on google since last 2 months and found too many solutions all mix up and not able to understand single best working solution.

Comment: `mod_proxy` is what you need. Check details [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/proxy-howto.html)

Comment: thank you for your reply slayedbylucifer and suggest mod_proxy. I have tried to configure in httpd.conf file present at /etc/apache2/httpd.conf but this file is empty. As i installed apache and tomcat both using apt-get command line. Kindly explain little in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

First, create sampleweb file in /etc/apache2/sites-available
    sudo touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy_your_sampleweb

Second, add the following in above sampleweb host file.
    sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy_your_sampleweb

```
#For forwarding everything
<Proxy *>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Third, enable sampleweb site
    sudo a2ensite proxy_your_sampleweb

Forth, reload apache2 configuration
    sudo service apache2 reload

Fifth, access your tomcat app using 80 port.
    http://<>/

if you want to redirect only specific context like sampleweb, you can customise the above to limit only your sampleweb request to tomcat.
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy_your_sampleweb

```
#For forwarding only required contexts
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /sampleweb http://localhost:8080/sampleweb
ProxyPassReverse /sampleweb http://localhost:8080/sampleweb
```